# How to exit and run the Python IDLE shell in one step

Tags: python, linux, shell, restart, python-idle

Is it possible both to exit and run the Python IDLE in one step? If so, what steps should I take to do this?

I want to do something similar to Shell -> Restart Shell (Ctrl+F6) in Windows IDLE.   I could do Ctrl-D, up-arrow, enter but I'd like to do this in one step.

The following didn't really answer my question...
[How do I restart the IDLE Python Shell in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188805/how-do-i-restart-the-idle-python-shell-in-linux)

Comment: Hmm... Restart shell works on my Ubuntu Precise Pangolin guest OS... What OS are you running? Did you install from source or use your OS's installer?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 5 and 6. They are all from the OSs' installer.

Answer (score 0):

The related question you linked to does, in fact, give you a hint as to how to do this.

Edit your menu entry for Idle and just remove the default -n after the command path and filename. When you restart Idle, the Shell menu item you are familiar with from windows will be available with all the usual functionality.